# Set the title of UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uibutton

how can I set the title of an UIButton?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The same way you can set separate title if needed for highlighted and selected state (changing last parameter)

Answer (score 2):

//PSEUDO CODE

```
UIButton *myButton;

[myButton setTitle: @"I'm a f%&%$$%&& button!!!!!!!! yay" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```